# Is it possible to write a program to print all pairs that add to k from an input array of size n

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, np

Is it possible to write a program to print all pairs that add to k from an input array of size n. If so how? I heard this problem is NP-Complete. I was wondering if we can provide a solution to this problem in typical programming languages like C/C++

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried. But the algorithm is exponential. It is basically by checking out all combinations of the numbers in the array and comparing the sum with the value k.

Comment: If its NP complete, can you do better than exponential?

Comment: What should I say if I get this question in a job interview

Comment: Nope it is mathematically impossible to solve with a computer, you can only do it by hand

Comment: I heard there is an approximate algorithm for it. If anyone can explain then that would be useful.

Comment: I don't know why people have voted down and closed this. Anyways, you can read more about it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Comment: Now, i know. The question is wrong. Sorry for all the hassle.

Answer (score 4):

It can't be NP-Complete as there is an obvious O(n^2) solution with two nested loops over the array and checking if the sum is k.

There is however an O(n) solution using hashtable. Here is the solution in C#:

```
        int[] ar = new int[] { 1, 4, 6, 8 };
        int k = 7;

        HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>();
        foreach (int n in ar)
        {
            if (set.Contains(n))
                Console.WriteLine("({0}, {1})", k - n, n);

            set.Add(k - n);
        }
```

Comment: I am not sure that this will work. Can you provide a link to ideone, so that i can try to test your solution. I am not familiar with C#.

Comment: "a link to ideone"? What do you mean?

Comment: Ideone.com . This is a site where you can run your program. Sorry for not being clear. Submit your program in C# and give me the link.

Comment: [Code](http://ideone.com/ulRr6). Question asked was - "a program to print all pairs that add to k from an input array of size n." Answer should have been {(15), (1,4,4,6)}.

Comment: there is no pair that add up to 15 in the array (1,4,4,6,15), man. What are you talking about? pair = two :)

Comment: Ah ! Sorry, with all the NP mentioned in the question, i deviated to a more general problem. My bad.